# Column name in CSV file and control file are different while loading in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to load data in oracle database. Input is CSV file. In this CSV file, column names are different from column names present in database table. Control file is being generated using column names present in database.

Is there any way to load such data?

Any input would of great help.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299619/mapping-fields-in-oracle-sql-loader

Comment: An example would help - the DB table structure, CSV file (a few lines at least) and control file; plus what happens now and what you want to happen. I don't know if you're talking about a header row that you could skip, or the fields being in a different order to the columns, or something else. Actually it isn't even entirely clear if you're using SQL\*Loader (implied by ref. to control file), an external table, or some client-specific load mechanism.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include a sample of the input file including the header line, the control file, the database table schema, and (perhaps most importantly) **the errors you get when you run SQL*Loader**. Also, is there a reason you can't use a text replacement tool such as `sed` to just change the name of the column in the .CSV file to whatever you'd like it to be? Or simply `tail` the file to eliminate the first line? What OS are you using? Thanks.

Comment: There is no need to have same names of the column header in csv and table columms. You do not actually load the column header in the table. Use `option(skip=1)`

Comment: Yeah Tejash. That's right. Thank you :). This worked.